# Managing DNS lookup limit of SPF for a domain with many sending email services

Tags: spf

I am webmastering for a sports association, and I would need to set up SPF records for the club's domain. However, I'm exceeding the 10 lookup limit, and would need guidance how to best resolve the issue.

The setup is such that the club provides email addresses under the club's domain for its functionaries (board members and some other persons, about 10 in total). Due to

1. the club is bootstrapping on money and has a very limited email plan from its domain provider; and;
2. the persons prefer to receive the emails sent to their club domain email in their personal email inboxes,

the club email addresses have been setup as redirects: e.g. my club email redirects to my personal Gmail, and similarly for others. Functionaries with club emails use a variety of email service providers, ranging from free ones to work/educational institution email providers.

Based on admittedly limited understanding, after some reading on how I should set up the SPF records, I thought I would need to include a policy for all the various email service providers that are used to send email under the club's domain. I would be grateful if someone can verify whether my assumption is correct.

If yes, the problem is the 10 DNS lookup limit. Due to the need to allow sending from multiple email providers (including but not limited to Gmail, Yahoo and Hotmail), I am exceeding the 10 lookup limit. Is there any way to tackle the issue on SPF policy level, or would it be necessary to consolidate the services used to send email before setting up SPF?

EDIT: The current SPF record is just

```
v=spf1 +all
```

I started drafting the following entry to include Gmail, Yahoo, Hotmail/Outlook and University of Helsinki email:

```
v=spf1 a mx include:_spf.google.com include:_spf.mail.yahoo.com include:spf.protection.outlook.com include:spf-a.outlook.com include:spf-b.outlook.com include:spf-a.hotmail.com include:_spf-ssg-b.microsoft.com include:_spf-ssg-c.microsoft.com include:_spf1.helsinki.fi include:_spf2.helsinki.fi include:_spf.lyyti.fi include:spf.creamailer.com include:_spf-dc2.successfactors.com ~all
```

Comment: Please show the actual SPF record. You can replace the actual domain with example.com if you feel it necessary, but the easiest way to analyze the problem would be the actual domain.

Comment: @GeraldSchneider, I edited in the current SPF and the one that I started drafting (and fixed the broken title of the question).

Comment: **I thought I would need to include a policy for all the various email service providers that are used to send email under the club's domain.**
Google, Yahoo, etc. aren't sending email on behalf of your domain. You don't need those entities in your SPF record. Forwarding club email to another email provider and then responding to that email from said provider doesn't send the email "under the club's domain".

Comment: @joeqwerty you are, of course, correct. Thanks for the clarification. What about the scenario if an external sender sends an email to an address under the club's domain, which redirects to several email addresses (also outside the club's domain)? I would expect that no SPF would be required for the club's domain, as it's not the original sender.

Comment: That is correct. If john@externaldomain.com sends an email to bob@club.com and that email gets forwarded to bob@gmail.com and then bob@gmail.com replies to the email, it is sent from bob@gmail.com, not bob@club.com.

Comment: @JoelLehikoinen Regarding the "What about the scenario..." question: It might break the SPF authentication for the original senders domain in many cases, since your servers forwarding the emails are not listed in the senders SPF record. Regarding the original question: As a quick win you may consider removing the MX and A mechanisms in your SPF records, if they don't actually point to mail servers used by your club to _send out_ emails. It saves you 2 lookups instantly.

Answer (score 0):

Use one domain for outbound mail and put that in your SPF? Use on SMTP gateway who send the mail to the internet and to external recipients.

Or migrate to M365 there you can have many domains as you want.

Answer (score 0):

- SPF limits record evaluation to 10 lookups
- You need to include more than 10 records, each one counting as one lookup
- Even if you don't include 10 records, included records can have other `include` terms too, and the lookups will count towards your limit. You don't control those included records, so you'll never know how many lookups they will generate.

Based on the above, it is pretty clear that you cannot do what you want by just `include`'ing all providers in your SPF record.

Here are some possible solutions:

1. Sign-up to an email service. Ask all club members to point the SMTP server on their MUA to the provider's server, and/or use their webmail. List their servers on your SPF record as an authorized sender.

   - Cons: subscription fees. Shared IP spam/ban issues.
2. Setup a SMTP submission server. Similar to the above, except that *you* are the email service provider, and has exclusive use of the server address (so no spam/ban issues caused by others).

   - Cons: costly to setup. It may be costly to maintain.
3. Recursively expand all included SPF records manually, merge then into one single record, and make the result your SPF record.

   - Cons: you will need to constantly monitor all included records for changes. Record can hit DNS size limits, which would require splitting. It can be a PITA to do it manually. Prone to errors. Not 100% reliable.
4. Same as above, but create a program/script to replace all manual work.

   - Cons: can be costly. Program can have bugs. It needs API/integration support from your DNS host for full automation.

Comment: Thanks for the comprehensive answer. All the proposed solutions are pretty much out of scope for our club. Fortunately, we haven't had any major issues with outgoing mail, so doing nothing is a viable option, if there is no easy solution.